# Averaging precision and recall when using cross validation

Tags: classification, cross-validation, precision-recall

I have performed classification using multiple classifiers for a 2-classes labelled data, and I used 5-fold cross validation. For each fold I calculated tp, tn, fp, and fn. Then I calculated the accuracy, precision, recall and F-score for each test. My question is, when I want to average the results, I took the average of accuracies, but can I average precision, recall and the F-score as well? Or would this be mathematically wrong?
P.S. The datasets used in each fold are well balanced in terms of the number of instances per class.

Thanks.

Comment: I encountered your same problem regarding computing the F-measure (harmonic mean of precision and recall) using cross-validation. In [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.186.8880) they actually demonstrated that computing the F-measure on the complete set, and not averaging, is the less biased method. I hope this can help

Comment: @markusian Please add this as an answer! It is by far the most important thing on this page!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $F$-score, assuming you're using the usual definition, is already a combination of the precision and recall. Specifically, it is the harmonic mean of them. In other words $$F_1 = 2\cdot\frac{\textrm{precision} \cdot \textrm{recall}}{\textrm{precision} + \textrm{recall}}$$ It's meant to capture the 'effectiveness' of a system where the user places equal weights on precision and recall. There's an extension, called the $F_\beta$ score, which gives $\beta$ times more weight to recall than precision.
$$ F_\beta = (1+\beta^2) \frac{\textrm{precision} \cdot \textrm{recall}}{(\beta^2 \cdot\textrm{precision}) + \textrm{recall}} $$
On the other hand, if you're asking whether you can average the 5 $F$ scores (one from each fold), then the answer is yes. In fact, that's the typical way to report a system's performance!

Just be aware that there are some issues with using these values to make inferences about the classifiers' generalization error. For example, a $t$-test between the $F$ scores for one classifier and the $F$ scores for another classifier is going to be too optimistic.

Comment: Yes, I used the first formula. This means that averaging the F-score from the different tests yields similar results to averaging precision and recall and then calculating the F-score from them. I tried this on the results I have and it was almost the same. Thanks.